# Using token authentication with flutter swagger_dart_code_generator

Tags: flutter, rest, swagger, generator

I'm currently learning Flutter and how to develop mobile apps with a server backend. I've came across the library [swagger_dart_code_generator](https://pub.dev/packages/swagger_dart_code_generator), which generates Dart Models and API functions based on a swagger file.
I have followed the example they have and I managed to get myself a basic working REST Application.
So my request to `api.userLogin();` returns a `JWTToken` as expected.

The next step was figuring out, how to send a `JWTToken` with requests that require authentication, but I found no examples in their GitHub repository, nor did I see a Member Function in the generated code, that lets me set headers to the HTTP request.

What I am basically trying to do, is to send the JWTToken I already got to a function like `api.getSuperSecretUserInfo();` and get a response from the Server other than a "*401 Unauthorised*".

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.